# FTP lib in java for searching

Tags: ftp, javadoc, java

I am looking for a java lib for FTP that allows you to download files and also search the folder through their names as well.
[I found one](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j) here but I dont think it allow searching.
Thanks in meekness

Answer (score 0):

I think [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/)'s [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) would do the trick for you.